# How to hide the ok button on the keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to hide the ok button on the standard keyboard.

I have already tried without success

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Do you know how to do ?

[image]

Comment: can you upload your keyboard picture with ok button

Comment: done, updated first message.

Comment: What do you want to do by removing?

Comment: if you don't want your edit text to shrink bottom try my answer below it'll prevent edittext from shrinking

Answer (score 0):

this will remove enter key from keyboard

> `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`
>   or `android:inputType="textPersonName"`

Comment: Why do you want to remove?

Comment: if you remove inputType the key become enter